# shortening content of options inside a select tag

Tags: php

I need to make `<option>` content shorter.

```
<select id='seltop'> 
<?php   
$stmt = $db->query("select id, title from posts where status not in ('archive') order by date desc");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        if(strlen($row['title'] > 25)) {$title = substr($row['title'], 0, 25) . '. . .';}
        else {$title = $row['title'];}  
        echo "<option>" . $title . "</option>\n";
    }
?>
</select>
```

only first `<option>` is short (with elipsis).
all others `<option>` tags have full length.
what is wrong ?

Comment: full length as in: longer than 25 characters?

Comment: `if(strlen($row['title'] > 25))` have you noticed that you don't close the `strlen()` function well? You're closing it after the 25, it shouldn't be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strlen($row['title'] > 25))
```

This is probably asking "is the length of `$row['title'] > 25` true?". I don't know what your database contains, but apparently that evaluates to false when you see the full title.

What you wanted to do was `if(strlen($row['title']) > 25)`. Damn typos.